# Laravel Sanctum API Tokens for non SPA

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I have recently upgraded an old app to Laravel 8 and subsequently installed Sanctum for api authentication. I understand the use case for Sanctum when the front end is a SPA but as my app is legacy it uses a combination of react and Laravel blade views.

When a user logs in it generates a token, where you can then only see the plainTextToken once which is fine for a SPA as it can then be stored in a global state.

My question is what is the best practice for when an app isn't a SPA with a global state. For example if i have routes for an authenticated user i don't want to have to generate a token for every request. I have thought about storing the token as a cookie and using the cookie value for each api request but that doesn't seem to be a good practice to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Token based authentication is not related to if your application is an SPA's or not.
The whole idea is to generate a token for a user and this same token should be sent with all the requests that needs to be authenticated, if you have trouble with this part check the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens).

you can use cookie, http-cookie, local-storage or global state to store the token on the front end.

Once you send the token in the headers of your requests you are basically telling Laravel who is the authenticated user, you don't need to create a token per request since the same token created for a user can be used until it expires (also check the above link for more information)

Regarding good practice, storing the token in a cookie/local-storage will make your website vulnerable to [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/),

> XSS attacks occur when an attacker uses a web application to send malicious code, generally in the form of a browser side script, to a different end user.

You have to validate/encode any user content that may be visible to other users to defend against XSS. Of course do your own research and apply what you think is best.

Answer (score 1):

I have this question too. It seems that Sanctum is ONLY for SPA even though the documentation does not mention that specifically. Non SPA where you may open link in new tab (or simply enter the same url on new tab) apparently will not carry the same authentication. You are correct about using cookie, the cookie value can be stolen.

The solution that I can think of is simply by not using Sanctum and the api routes. Instead, use web routes and declare the api routes inside web.php (e.g. Route::get('/api/user'..). Then you can check whether the request is an api or web request inside controller or with a middleware and returns a view or json accordingly. This is not an elegant solution but it works.